# String Concatenation Error Using Perls Dot Operator

Tags: string, perl, concatenation, user-input

I am trying to read input of two strings from the user keyboard, store them in two variables and concatenate the two strings together using the Perls dot operator.

Research I found online shows an example similar to what I am trying to accomplish. This example uses only one string variable in the concatenation but I think something similar should be able to concatenate multiple variables together:

```
$name = checkbook'; 
$filename = '/tmp/' . $name . '.tmp'; 

#$filename now contains "/tmp/checkbook.tmp"
```

(http://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010003.shtml)

my code is displayed in the following - however, I am still getting the undesired concatenation :

```
$stringa=<STDIN>;
$stringb=<STDIN>;
print $stringa.$stringb;
```

compiled using perl (path)

output

```
     nein
     ja
     nein
     ja
```

instead of the desired output:

```
 nein
 ja
 neinja
```

why am I not getting the concatenation output I think it should produce?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "chomp" to remove the trailing string "\n", like this:

```
$stringa=<STDIN>;
$stringb=<STDIN>;
chomp($stringa);
chomp($stringb);
print $stringa.$stringb;
```

Comment: And probably add `. "\n"` after `$stringb` in the `print` statement (or don't chomp `$stringb`).